# The whitelist in PhoneGap Build isn't working when I connect to a server with https

Tags: android, phonegap-build

I'm having a problem with the Android version of my app, created with PhoneGap Build.

I have setup a whitelist so Android doesn't block access to my server, and have tried these settings in config.xml

```
<access origin="https://casechek.com" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="https://api.casechek.com" />
<access origin="htts://casechek.com" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="http://api.casechek.com" />
<access origin="*" />
```

When I connect to my server with http:// it works, but when I try with https:// it doesn't work.

If I open my app in a browser or install it on iOS via PhoneGap the https:// connection works fine.

So I only get 404 responses in Android, when I connect to https://

Is there something else I need to set in the config file?

This is my full config.xml

```
    <name>Casechek</name>

    <description>
        Casechek application to track Instrument Trays.
    </description>

    <author email="support@casechek.com" href="http://www.casechek.com">
        Mike Bates
    </author>

    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustResize" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />

    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>

    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" version="2.2.0" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" version="0.3.6" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" version="0.2.15" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />

    <access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
    <access origin="geo:*" launch-external="yes" />
    <access origin="*" />

    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi"      src="assets/img/icon/android/drawable-ldpi/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi"      src="assets/img/icon/android/drawable-mdpi/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi"      src="assets/img/icon/android/drawable-hdpi/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi"     src="assets/img/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xxhdpi"    src="assets/img/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi/icon-144-xxhdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios"     width="29" height="29"    src="assets/img/icon/ios/Icon-Small.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios"     width="58" height="58"    src="assets/img/icon/ios/Icon-Small@2x.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios"     width="87" height="87"    src="assets/img/icon/ios/Icon-Small@3x.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios"     width="40" height="40"    src="assets/img/icon/ios/Icon-Small-40.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios"     width="80" height="80"    src="assets/img/icon/ios/Icon-Small-40@2x.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios"     width="120" height="120"  src="assets/img/icon/ios/Icon-Small-40@3x.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios"     width="50" height="50"    src="assets/img/icon/ios/Icon-Small-50.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios"     width="100" height="100"  src="assets/img/icon/ios/Icon-Small-50@2x.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios"     width="150" height="150"  src="assets/img/icon/ios/Icon-Small-50@3x.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios"     width="57" height="57"    src="assets/img/icon/ios/Icon.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios"     width="114" height="114"  src="assets/img/icon/ios/Icon@2x.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios"     width="120" height="120"  src="assets/img/icon/ios/Icon-60@2x.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios"     width="180" height="180"  src="assets/img/icon/ios/Icon-60@3x.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios"     width="72" height="72"    src="assets/img/icon/ios/Icon-72.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios"     width="144" height="144"  src="assets/img/icon/ios/Icon-72@2x.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios"     width="76" height="76"    src="assets/img/icon/ios/Icon-76.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios"     width="152" height="152"  src="assets/img/icon/ios/Icon-76@2x.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone"                          src="assets/img/icon/windows/icon-42-tile.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone"                          src="assets/img/icon/windows/icon-62-tile.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone"                          src="assets/img/icon/windows/icon-173-tile.png" />

    <!-- Android -->
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi"    src="assets/img/splash/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="land-ldpi"    src="assets/img/splash/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi"    src="assets/img/splash/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="land-mdpi"    src="assets/img/splash/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi"    src="assets/img/splash/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="land-hdpi"    src="assets/img/splash/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi"   src="assets/img/splash/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="land-xhdpi"   src="assets/img/splash/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" />

    <!-- iPhone and iPod touch -->
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios"     width="320"  height="480"    src="assets/img/splash/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios"     width="480"  height="320"    src="assets/img/splash/ios/screen-iphone-landscape.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios"     width="640"  height="960"    src="assets/img/splash/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios"     width="960"  height="640"    src="assets/img/splash/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-2x.png" />

    <!-- iPhone 5 / iPod Touch (5th Generation) -->
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios"     width="640"  height="1136"   src="assets/img/splash/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios"     width="1136" height="640"    src="assets/img/splash/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-568h-2x.png" />

    <!-- iPhone 6 -->
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios"     width="750"  height="1334"   src="assets/img/splash/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-667h-2x.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios"     width="1242" height="2208"   src="assets/img/splash/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-736h-3x.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios"     width="2208" height="1242"   src="assets/img/splash/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-736h-3x.png" />

    <!-- iPad -->
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios"     width="768"  height="1004"   src="assets/img/splash/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios"     width="1004" height="768"    src="assets/img/splash/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" />

    <!-- Retina iPad -->
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios"     width="1536" height="2048"   src="assets/img/splash/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-@2x.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios"     width="2048" height="1536"   src="assets/img/splash/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-@2x.png" />

    <!-- Winphone -->
    <gap:splash gap:platform="winphone"                             src="assets/img/splash/windows/screen-portrait.png" />

</widget>
```

Answer (score 1):

@mike,
you have several mistakes in your `config.xml` and I have fix for your issues.

1. I will assume the first part of you post is a typo, where you write `htts:`
2. The top part of your `config.xml` is missing. I assume a typo also.
3. The following code does nothing. `<feature (...)>` has been deprecated for *Phonegap Build*. SEE: [#12](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#012) of [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

   `<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
   <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
   <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>`
4. You need to source all your plugin from NPM from now on.

   - [Deprecation of Public Plugins on PhoneGap Build](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/09/04/public-plugin-deprecation-on-build/)
   - [config.xml gets an update - part 2 !!!!!!](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/11/19/config_xml_changes_part_two/) **This starts November, 20th 2015 at 1:00 PM PST**

On #4, the volunteer support group has been complaining bitterly about unannounced changes. I think they are getting the message.

### Your fix

First, many of your details are here: [HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md).

Add this to your `config.xml`

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" /> <!-- Required for iOS9 -->
```

Add this to your `index.html`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
         content="default-src *; 
                  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
                  script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

### NOTE: BY ADDING THESE CHANGES YOUR APP IS NOW INSECURE AND SUBJECT TO MALICIOUS ATTACKS.

To make secure read: [HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)